# How can you edit the axis position on a line chart in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, axis

When i create a line chart in openpyxl it sets the "Axis position" to "Between tick marks" by default. I would like to set it to "On tick marks" but i have not found a way to do this yet

[This is how the chart currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx046.png)

[This is how i'd like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UXrN.png)

Here is my code

```
from datetime import date
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis, ChartLines

def test_chart():
               
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    rows = [
        ['Date', 'Value',],
        [date(2020, 1, 1), 10,],
        [date(2020, 2, 2), 25,],
        [date(2020, 3, 3), 50,],
        [date(2020, 4, 4), 30,],
        [date(2020, 5, 5), 25,],
        [date(2020, 6, 6), 20,],
    ]

    for row in rows:
        ws.append(row)

    test_chart = LineChart()
    test_chart.title = 'Line Chart'
    test_chart.style = 13
    test_chart.y_axis.title = 'Title'
    test_chart.y_axis.crossAx = 500
    test_chart.x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
    test_chart.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "months"
    test_chart.x_axis.number_format = 'mm/yy'
    test_chart.x_axis.majorGridlines = ChartLines()

    data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=7)
    test_chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    dates = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=7)
    test_chart.set_categories(dates)

    ws.add_chart(test_chart, 'D1')

    wb.save('test_chart.xlsx')

test_chart()
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure, but something like `test_chart.x_axis.AxisBetweenCategories` or `test_chart.y_axis.AxisBetweenCategories` may work